# x64 assembly SHR on 32 bit register clears the high bits of corresponding 64 bit register--why?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I've noticed when I use SHR on a 32 bit register, the high bits of its corresponding 64 bit register get cleared. But, if I use SHR on its 16 bit register, all the high bits are preserved. Why? This behaviour occurs in both NASM and MASM using x64 assembly.

Is there any way to preserve the high bits of the 64 bit register when using SHR on its 32 bit corresponding register? (I mean instead of just copying those bits elsewhere like into a different register.)

e.g.,

```
mov rbx, 8877665544332211h      

shr ebx, 8 ; now RBX contains 0000000000443322
[versus]
shr bx, 8  ; RBX would now contain 8877665544330022
```

So what I want to have happen is this:

```
mov rbx, 8877665544332211h      
shr ebx, 8 ; RBX should now contain 8877665500443322
```

Comment: This is a fundamental architectural design property of the amd64 architecture.  32 bit instructions with register destinations clear the upper 32 bits of the register.

Comment: Do you need this upper-preserving 32-bit right shift in a loop?  Are you doing it on data from memory, where you could use XMM registers instead?  Like with AVX2 `vpsrlvd` with different shift counts for elements 0 and 1?  Or if the shift counts are always multiples of 8, use SSSE3 `pshufb` to move bytes and introduce zeros.

Comment: For scalar, some shift / and / BMI1 andn / or, perhaps?  Maybe BMI2 `rorx` could be useful to copy-and-shift if you're going to mask anyway, so the difference between shift and rotate doesn't matter.  Generally don't ask two questions in the same post; this is titled with the "why" part, and I'm not sure if your question about an upper-preserving right shift is something you actually need for something you're optimizing in asm, or if it's just part of the why.  As written, this seems like a duplicate.  If the upper-preserving shift is the real question, edit to be about that, the why is a dup.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I appreciate your responses. You've given me some useful alternatives.